# ASP .NET Webservice undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

We have an internal IIS web server and an external IIS Web server. When i publish the same web application, that uses a webservice, in both servers I get an error that the webservice class is undefined.

Below is my code in ASPX page

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm_orderset" runat="server">
      <Services>
          <asp:ServiceReference Path="OrdersetService.svc" />
      </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Here is the call in JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Ajax functions for retrieving and displaying comments
function getComments(componentid) {
    OrdersetService.getComments(componentid, onSuccess);
}
</script>
```

The call to the function doesnt do anything. here is what i find in the debug

**SCRIPT:5009: 'OrdersetService' is undefined**

**File: jsfunctions.js, Line: 8, Column: 5**

Comment: I am confused why you'd think declaring a service on the server would also create a Javascript symbol for the browser. Are you using some tool to generate a Javascript proxy class? Are you including that script in the web page?

Comment: I have not made any assumptions. I used the Script Manager to declare the Sevice so i can make a call to the getComments method as you can see in my javascript code. This works perfectly on one server and not in another. Hope i answered your question

Comment: The script has to get to the browser somehow, usually through a separate HTTP request. Use your browser's F12 tools to check the network traffic and see if you can find the request and whether it succeeded. If the script isn't successfully loaded the object will be undefined.

Comment: When i do F12  , that is what i receive... OrsersetService is undefined. The HTTP request cannot even be initiated if that is undefined.

Comment: I am not referring to the request sent by the OrsersetService. I am referring to the request that the browser sends to obtain the Javascript that defines the OrsersetService. The URL for the request will probably end in `.js`.

Comment: This is what Script Manager spits out: <script src="./OrdersetService.svc/js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I understand. Check your F12 network tab for a request to a URL that ends with `OrdersetService.svc/js` and see if it succeeded.

Comment: Are you familiar with `document.ready` and its purpose?

Comment: yes i do , what do you suggest

Comment: It seems like your call is being issued before the browser has loaded the script. Have you tried wrapping the call in `document.ready`?

Comment: No but i think you pointed me to where the problem could be. the second server requires SSL and i might need to review the webconfig configurations.

Comment: John Wu.. Thank you for helping me through this i was able to find the issue. You directed me on where i should be looking which was the HTTP request. After a few tweaks i did get a response which was a 500 but from that point i was able to adjust my webconfig settings to resolve the error. How can i give you a vote?

Comment: Thank you for thinking of me, Met. I have plenty of reputation so I suggest we just close the question. If you think your findings will help someone else please write an answer and mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue was due to the second server requiring SSL binding. Changed my service configuration in webconfig to get to the result.

Here is the end result of my webconfig

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Online_Power_Plan.OrdersetServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>          
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="Online_Power_Plan.OrdersetService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Online_Power_Plan.OrdersetServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="Online_Power_Plan.OrdersetService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```